# Macrobenchmarking Android Confusion

Tags: android, performance, android-jetpack, macrobenchmark

I am going through Macrobenchmarking documentation : https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/benchmarking/benchmarking-overview

It mentions:

> It allows you to control compiling, starting and stopping your
> application to directly measure actual app startup or scrolling,
> instead of only the specific jitted, hot functions, with all disk
> accesses cached.

I understand the first part about controlling compile, startup as benchmark provides us with those options while writing the tests. But unable to understand what the second part means **only the specific jitted, hot functions, with all disk accesses cached**.

Can someone help me understand this. Is this related to AOT compilation or something else?

Comment: Have you seen: https://source.android.com/docs/core/runtime/jit-compiler

Comment: Yes I did read about JIT / ART and how the changes have been done in Android over the years (Recent changes regarding Baseline profiles), there's an excellent article as well: https://medium.com/proandroiddev/android-runtime-how-dalvik-and-art-work-6e57cf1c50e5
 Just wanted to confirm whether this is related to compilation only or something else

Comment: Honestly I think that particular quote `instead of only specific jitted, hot functions, with all disk accesses cached` refers to what is done with/by the [Microbenchmarking library](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/benchmarking/benchmarking-overview#microbenchmark) as a contrast to the Macrobenchmarking library as that library has `warmed up Just in Time (JIT), disk accesses cached` wording.

Answer (score 1):

With the macrobenchmark library you gain full control over several states in contrast to the Microbenchmark library.

This is related to JIT (Just-in-Time) and AOT (Ahead-of-Time) compilation.

I agree that the phrasing is targeted at developers who already have an understanding of these libraries and it will be updated shortly.